# How to define a linear ordering on a type?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define [a conjunction function for 4-valued logic (false, true, null, and error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945485/how-to-define-functions-with-overlapping-patterns/42945657). In my case the conjunction is equivavlent to `min` function on linear order `false < error < null < true`.

```
datatype bool4 = JF | JT | BN | BE

instantiation bool4 :: linear_order
begin

fun leq_bool4 :: "bool4 ⇒ bool4 ⇒ bool" where
  "leq_bool4 JF b = True"
| "leq_bool4 BE b = (b = BE ∨ b = BN ∨ b = JT)"
| "leq_bool4 BN b = (b = BN ∨ b = JT)"
| "leq_bool4 JT b = (b = JT)"

instance proof
  fix x y z :: bool4
  show "x ⊑ x"
    by (induct x) simp_all
  show "x ⊑ y ⟹ y ⊑ z ⟹ x ⊑ z"
    by (induct x; induct y) simp_all
  show "x ⊑ y ⟹ y ⊑ x ⟹ x = y"
    by (induct x; induct y) simp_all
  show "x ⊑ y ∨ y ⊑ x"
    by (induct x; induct y) simp_all
qed

end

definition and4 :: "bool4 ⇒ bool4 ⇒ bool4" where
  "and4 a b ≡ minimum a b"
```

I guess there must be an easier way to define a linear order in Isabelle HOL. Could you suggest a simplification of the theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ["Datatype_Order_Generator" AFP entry](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Datatype_Order_Generator.shtml).

Then it's as simple as importing `"$AFP/Datatype_Order_Generator/Order_Generator"` and declaring `derive linorder "bool4"`. Note that the constructors must be declared in the order you want them when defining your datatype.

Details on how to download and use the AFP locally can be found [here](https://www.isa-afp.org/using.shtml).

Comment: Thanks! It works. Maybe it will be helpful for somenone: `minimum` function must be replaced by `(if a ≤ b then a else b)` in the definition of `and4`.

Comment: What do you mean with `minimum`? `min` should work fine.

Comment: Yep, `min` works! In my original version of `and4` I use `minimum` from `HOL\Lattice\Lattice`